# xcache - What does enabling encoder/decoder/optimizer/assembler do?

Tags: php, optimization, assembly, disassembly, xcache

What do the enable-xcache optimizer & encoder/decoder do?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGqUm.png

There is configure flags `--enable-xcache-optimizer` `--enable-xcache-encoder` `--enable-xcache-decoder` what do these do?

Is `--enable-xcache` enough to maximize `xcache` with `PHP`?

Not very important but curious: What does the `--enable-xcache-assembler/disassembler` do?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the Xcache code.  It's FLOSS, so you can download it.  It enables you to do what [VLD](http://pecl.php.net/package/vld) does offline.  I am lost as to why you'd want to embed this sort of functionality into an Opcode/data cache function.  What happened to "render unto Caesar here?

Comment: I just wasn't sure what purposes those configs would do to php.  I thought xcache just cached things. I found out about these other flags--I feel like I was missing something.

Comment: I wasn't joking about FLOSS.  It's amazing what you discover when you look through the source of some packages.  I sometimes suspect that the pervading philosophy is that "I don't need to document, because the source is available for inspection." But seriously IMO, if you want to look at the PHP generated "assembler code" then VLD is a better option.  :-)

Comment: I didn't think of it that way.  What a nice way to think of open source software with little to none documentation!

Comment: @Reado, maybe by the time your rep gets into triple digits you'll begin to understand.  Those who answer Qs aren't an infinite free resource.  We give focused As to well researched Qs.  We aren't a substitute so that OPs don't have to bother doing the work.  I knew what the assembler/disassembler did and pointed the OP to the mainstream package in this area which is well documented.   As to the other Qs -- the source is clear to understand.  Why should I read and paraphrase.  Pay me $100/hr and I'll do it for you :-)